# log4net - creating only one logfile

Tags: c#, xml, logging, log4net

I am using log4net and when I'm running my application, several logfiles are created. 
It appears the log4net is creating a new logfile whenever the time-format changes, meaning I end up with a new logfile whenever a minute has passed.

I have probably missunderstod the xml syntax used, but I'm not sure where its wrong (maybe RollingFileAppender?).

Here's the xml file:

```
<log4net>

  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level [%thread] %logger:%line - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd_hhmm'.log'"/>
    <file value="Boghe"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level [%thread] %logger:%line - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
  </root>

</log4net>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you **really** want just one file then you should use the normal file appender:

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#FileAppender

Based on your comments I assume your application runs for a "short" time and therefore you want to have some date / time information in your log file name. This you can do like this:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Boghe%date{yyyyMMdd_hhmm}.log" />
```

**Update:**

Configuration Sample (that works for me):

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
   <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString"
         value="c:\temp\Boghe%date{yyyyMMdd_hhmm}.log" />

   <appendToFile value="true" />
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date - %message%newline" />
   </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's more like what I want. I can't seem to get it to work though, it crashes, could you show how it would look like <appender> ... </appender>?

Comment: the  %date{yyyyMMdd_hhmm}  is giving me a parser error. Any idea why?

Comment: Which version of log4net do you have? Can you maybe post the error you get? Do you use internal debugging to see this error?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3173/discussion-between-stefan-egli-and-kaiserjohaan)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your date pattern to something like

```
<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
```

This will roll your logfile once a day.

---

**Example:**
With this configuration

```
<file value="Foo" />
<StaticLogFileName value="false">
<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd_hhmm"/>
```

you are telling the file appender to create a new logfile every minute (if you are writing something to the logs at least once a minute).

Say you started your application at `17:00:00 on 09/21/2011`. You output logging information every second.
This means that for the first 60 seconds (until 17:00:59) all output will be into a file named `Foo20110921_1700`.
At `17:01:00` the next output occurs and the file will be 'rolled over', meaning a new file `Foo20110921_1701` is created.
For the next 60 seconds all output will be into this new file. The same will happen again at `17:02:00`, `17:03:00` and so forth.

---

See [RollingFileAppender documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.html) for more information

Comment: I want the file to be named like "yyyyMMdd_hhmm" though. If I change it to "yyyyMMdd" I dont get the hours and mins in the filename

Comment: why would you want that? If you want to have the start time of the application just output it to the logfile

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you don't want to roll by date, use the Size value

```
    <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
```

So you will roll your files every 10MB.

Comment: I still want the logfile to be named like the date, "yyyyMMdd_hhmm" though. If I just change the rollingStyle it just names the files 'Boghe'